# USB wireless adapter drivers fail to install

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I am currently working on doing a fresh install of windows on my sisters computer as we were upgrading to the ultimate version of Windows 7.

She uses [this wireless usb network adapter](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/adapters/dwa-130-wireless-n-usb-adapter) to connect to the internet. I have all the proper driver installation files but when I go through the setup it gets to the point where it asks me to insert the device into the computer and it won't let me go past. No matter what I try or what USB port the adapter is in the software fails to recognize it.

I find it extremely unlikely that the device itself is faulty as it worked just fine 2 days ago before the format and reinstallation of Windows.

Am I out of luck here and just need to go purchase a new adapter or does anyone have any recommendations for things I can try to get this thing working again?

Comment: What OS was on before?

Comment: I followed "this adapter" and [this page](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/support/product/dwa-130-wireless-n-usb-adapter) asks me for a revision. Can you find this on your adapter? Are you sure that you have the driver for the correct revision of the dongle and that the setup files are for Windows 7?

Comment: @Luke Windows 7 home. And I am positive that these are Windows 7 drivers. I will double check the revision number

Comment: We need to know the hardware version of the adapter and whether you're installing 32-bit or 64-bit Windows. (Or just get a new adapter, they're widely [available](http://www.mwave.com/mwave/SKUSearch.asp?px=FO&scriteria=AA98953) for $10 or less.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple of suggestions:

1. Install the drivers for your chipset (motherboard) or make sure usb is working with some other usb device (like a mouse).
2. [Install the drivers manually.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631789/how-to-install-driver-with-a-cat-file)

If that doesn't cut it. Make sure that you download the correct revision and OS from the [support site](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/support/product/dwa-130-wireless-n-usb-adapter), log in as a new user (temporary) and retry the installation steps as described in the driver package.

Comment: Your original comment regarding the revision number was spot on. Can't remember how/where I originally got the drivers I was trying to use but they were for hardware revision C and my device was hardware revision E. Everything worked out when I downloaded appropriate ones. Thanks for the help, I completely overlooked that

Comment: Ah yes, typical poorly written installers which fail to detect a vital thing like the revision of the firmware on the device they are supposed to support. They have caused me some grief in the past...

Comment: It's not the firmware revision, it's the *hardware* revision. And if they use the standard driver installer, they can't detect distinct hardware because their installer won't even be invoked for hardware it doesn't claim it can support. And, of course, it's often impossible to release a driver that will support hardware that doesn't even exist yet.

Comment: right. the firmware should return the hardware revision. you make a gadget and call it 1448; henceforth it is *1448*. new hw? new firmware? still 1488. when driver installer detects 1488 on the bus it tells the device _through the firmware_ hey! wtf is ur version number? is this driver new enough for you? Sure this is not as easy if you do not control the manufactured chip or use it "as is", but its far from impossible to notify the user when you detect that "whoa I can't see the device I'm supposed to support, please go http://HERE and dl the latest/correct driver for X"

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин That would be a disaster. If you cause the system to think a driver supports hardware it doesn't actually support, then the driver installation process will fail with an error rather than acquiring the right driver automatically. It is vital to the way the Windows driver fetch/update system works that a driver installer correctly and accurately register with the operating system what hardware it supports.

Comment: I think you are talking from a place of technical experience whereas I am arguing that installers which fail silently are very very annoying. We may even be on the same page, in essence.